# ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "lstm_cell" (type LSTMCell)

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, lstm, tensorflow2.0, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to build a combination of deep CNN-LSTM networks for binary classification using small datasets. I use reshape function to change the shape, and that perfectly works in Google Colab and my local Jupyter notebook but the following a value error while compiling this code in **AWS Sagemaker**.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_4202/2122205439.py in <cell line: 3>()
      1 tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
      2 
----> 3 model_06 = get_model()

/tmp/ipykernel_4202/3426630573.py in get_model()
     29     x = Reshape((64, 256))(x)
     30     print(f"After Reshaping(): {x.shape}")
---> 31     x = (LSTM(512, activation = "relu"))(x)
     32 
     33     # Fully Connected layer

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/layers/rnn/base_rnn.py in __call__(self, inputs, initial_state, constants, **kwargs)
    513 
    514     if initial_state is None and constants is None:
--> 515       return super(RNN, self).__call__(inputs, **kwargs)
    516 
    517     # If any of `initial_state` or `constants` are specified and are Keras

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68     finally:
     69       del filtered_tb

~/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow2_p38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/backend.py in bias_add(x, bias, data_format)
   6362   if len(bias_shape) == 1:
   6363     if data_format == 'channels_first':
-> 6364       return tf.nn.bias_add(x, bias, data_format='NCHW')
   6365     return tf.nn.bias_add(x, bias, data_format='NHWC')
   6366   if ndim(x) in (3, 4, 5):

ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "lstm_cell" (type LSTMCell).

Shape must be at least rank 3 but is rank 2 for '{{node lstm/lstm_cell/BiasAdd}} = BiasAdd[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NCHW"](lstm/lstm_cell/add, lstm/lstm_cell/BiasAdd/ReadVariableOp)' with input shapes: [?,2048], [2048].

Call arguments received by layer "lstm_cell" (type LSTMCell):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 256), dtype=float32)
  • states=('tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 512), dtype=float32)', 'tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 512), dtype=float32)')
  • training=None
```

Here is the model,

```
    # input layer
    inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(3, 256, 256), name="input_layer")
    
    # 2nd convolution block
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)
    x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
    
    # 2nd convolution block
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
    
    # 3rd convolution block
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
    
    # 4th convolution block
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
    
    # 5th convolution block
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
    
    print(f"Before Reshaping(): {x.shape}")
    
    # LSTM
    x = Reshape((64, 256))(x)
    print(f"After Reshaping(): {x.shape}")
    x = (LSTM(50, activation = "relu"))(x)

    # Fully Connected layer
    x = Flatten()(x)
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation = 'relu')(x)

    # Output layer
    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid", name="output_layer")(x)

    # Combine the inputs with the outputs into a model
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
    
    return model
```

Comment: Are you running this in a SageMaker notebook? Have you checked if the environment/libraries you are using is the same as what you had in Colab or your local Jupyter? This could be due to library issues but nothing in your code is SageMaker specific.

Comment: @KiritThadaka I got the same problem running on SageMaker. I tried to look at the libraries, but still can't find the way to solve it. Can you explain more about SageMaker specific as you mentioned? Thank you.